# get the sum value of specific key in given array and add row of count after specific completed index

Tags: php

Actual I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => person1
            [value] => 11
        )
   [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => person2
            [value] => 5
        )
 [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => person2
            [value] => 5
        )
  [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => person4
            [value] => 10
        )
)
```

Actually i need

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => person1
            [value] => 11
        )
//here i want new row index 1 array 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => total
            [value] => 11 //this value is the sum of index 1
        )
   [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => person2
            [value] => 5
        )
 [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => person2
            [value] => 5
        )
// here i want add new line index 4 array
[4] => Array
        (
            [name] => total
            [value] => 10  //this value is the sum of index 2 and 3
        )
  [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => person4
            [value] => 10
        )
// here i want add new line index 6 array

   [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => total
            [value] => 10 //this value is the sum of index 5
        )
)
```

Comment: Please add the code which generates the array as it will probably be an easy fix to that code.

Answer (score 0):

may this help you i have tried some step making grouping but sum is not correct but code may help you

```
$a = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'person1',
            'value' => 11,
        ),
   1 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'person2',
            'value' => 5,
        ),
 2 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'person2',
            'value' => 5,
        ),
 3 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'person4',
            'value' => 10,
        )
);


foreach($a as $c){
  $d[]=$c['name'];  
  $e[]=$c['value'];
}

//print_r($d);

$group = array();
foreach($d as $key=>$val){
     $group[$val][] = $e[$key];
}

// this loop for check the max number and count total price
$data   = array();
$total  = 0;
foreach($group as $key=>$val){
    for($i=0;$i<count($val);$i++){
       $data[]['name'] = $key;
       $data[]['value'] = $val[$i];
       $suma[] = $val[$i];

    }
    $sunmb =array_sum($suma);
    $data[]['name'] = 'total';
    $data[]['value'] = $sunmb;
 
 
  
 }
print_r($data);
```

You can check code run here https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/b1LD